# Get default app icon on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, windows

I want to get default application icon from `QFileIconProvider` but there are only:

**enum QFileIconProvider::IconType**

```
QFileIconProvider::Computer
QFileIconProvider::Desktop  
QFileIconProvider::Trashcan 
QFileIconProvider::Network  
QFileIconProvider::Drive    
QFileIconProvider::Folder   
QFileIconProvider::File
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I can navigate to some system executable file without icon to get this default icon using `QFileIconProvider`, but I think there should be another approach.
How to get this icon? Thanks.

**Update:**

I have found the identifier of default app icon - `IDI_APPLICATION`. The problem now is how to convert it to `QIcon` or `QString`? I have tried `QString::fromWCharArray(IDI_APPLICATION)` and `QString::fromStdWString(IDI_APPLICATION)` but it doesn't work, the app crashes. How to convert it? Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't look like this is [one of the options in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StandardPixmap-enum). Maybe there wasn't a good cross-platform icon? If you just need it for Windows, I can tell you how to retrieve the icon using standard Windows API calls.

Comment: @CodyGray
Yes, I need only for Windows.

Comment: An application is a file (and not any of the others), and that is the icon I get for applications with no icon. I think that actually is the default application icon.

Comment: @CodyGray

I have found that `IDI_APPLICATION` setting this default icon but how to convert it to `QIcon` or make `QString` from `MAKEINTRESOURCE`? Thanks.

Comment: @KennyOstrom

Yes, but it doesn't display any icon or displays default folder icon. So I should get default application icon.

Comment: @kenny I don't know what you mean by saying that "an application is a file". Sure, technically that's true, but all versions of Windows have a different icon that is used by default for files versus the one used for applications. Cobra has shown a screenshot of the default app icon here in the question (at least, the one used by Vista & 7; I can't remember what it looks like in 10). The default file icon is just a white sheet of paper with a folded corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

**Code:**

```
QIcon icon = QtWin::fromHICON(LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION));
```

Now it works.

Comment: Yup, that works. Only one problem: you will always get the 32x32 icon if you call `LoadIcon`. If that's the one you need, then this will work fine. If you want a smaller icon (like the standard 16x16 size), you won't get it; at best, the system will try to scale down the 32x32 icon and it'll look ugly. There are newer APIs that deal with these other icon sizes, but they're the tiniest bit more difficult to call than good old `LoadIcon` with its 2 simple parameters.

Comment: @CodyGray

Hi! Yes, 32x32 icon is fine in my case. The only think, it's Vista & 7 old style icon and in Win 10 it looks not so well. So I'm getting a new apps icon from `chkdsk.exe` (`QFileIconProvider`). Is there identifier like `IDI_APPLICATION` for new Win 10 apps icon? Thanks.

Comment: Uh, IDI_APPLICATION should be returning the generic application icon for the current OS. It should work fine in Windows 10. (If it isn't, then that's a new question—"why does `LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION)` return the old-style Vista/7 icon on Windows 10?" You mention chkdsk.exe, though, which is kind of confusing, because that doesn't use the generic application icon. It has its own custom icon, embedded into the binary.

Comment: @CodyGray
It's strange because I only get default icon from `chkdsk.exe`. Screenshot: [link](https://ibb.co/eVcz2a).

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the default icon from the application object. 
(May work on all platforms.)

```
QApplication app = QApplication(argc, argv);
QIcon icon = app.windowIcon();
```

Documentation link:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#windowIcon-prop

the function is available in `QGuiApplication`.

The `QApplication` inherits `QGuiApplication`.

Comment: Thanks. But what if my project app has already icon and I want default one to set for example in `QLabel`? Then this will return not default one.